# using other colors in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data set looks like this:
 x:

```
Date       variable     value
1/1/2012   A             10
1/1/2012   B             10
1/1/2012   C             10
1/1/2012   D             10
1/2/2012   A             10
1/2/2012   B             10
1/2/2012   C             10
1/2/2012   D             10
1/3/2012   A             10
1/3/2012   B             10
1/3/2012   C             10
1/3/2012   D             10
```

I am doing this:

```
rhg_cols1<- c("#000000","#F8766D","#7CAE00","#00BFC4","#C77CFF" ) 
ggplot(x, aes(Date, value, fill = variable, colour=variable)) +     geom_point()+     scale_fill_manual(values = rhg_cols1)
```

I am still seeing the default color. Can anybody tell me what is wrong? Better yet, rather than giving the specific colors as in rhg_cols1, I like to say low=red, high=black.

any input is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use

```
+ scale_colour_manual(values=rhg_cols1)
```

To set low and high colors you can use the `scale_XXXX_gradient()` function.

```
+ scale_colour_gradient(low="#000000", high="#C77CFF")
```

An example using `scale_XXXX_gradient` is [here](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/ggplot2-quick-heatmap-plotting/).

Comment: I will accept this answer but this was not really what I was looking for. I want to be able to pick the low and high colors rather than specifically stating all the colors.

Comment: @SeanKaplan I added another example. Does that help?